# Write unit test for function which return Observable

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, observable

## Problem Description

I'm trying to write test for simple class which is using `Observable`.
Test must be written for function `buildUseCaseObservable` which should first try to get data from network and if not succeed try to get from local database.

In the `buildUseCaseObservable` I'm using operator `first` which should filter data and return true if data is not null and empty.

If in the case of `rest.getData()` is called and data returned is not null I assume that `first` should return true and in that case `data.getData()` should not be called.

But in my case it seems that while testing function `first` is not called and both functions `rest.getData()` and `data.getData()` are always called.

## Question

What I'm doing wrong and how I can correct test?

#### DataInteractor.java

```
@PerActivity
public class DataInteractor extends Interactor {

    private RestService rest;
    private DataService data;

    @Inject
    DataInteractor(RestService rest, DataService data) {
        this.rest = rest;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    protected Observable buildUseCaseObservable() {
        return Observable.concat(
                rest.getData(),
                data.getData())
                .first(data -> data != null && !data.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

#### DataService.java

```
public interface DataService {
    Observable<List<IData>> getData();
}
```

#### RestService.java

```
public interface RestService {
    @GET("data")
    Observable<List<IData>> getData();
}
```

#### DataInteractorTest.java

```
public class DataInteractorTest {

    private DataInteractor interactor;

    @Mock private RestService mockedRest;
    @Mock private DataService mockedData;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.interactor = new DataInteractor(mockedRest, mockedData);
    }

    @Test
    public void firstDownloadDataFromNetwork() {
        when(mockedRest.getData()).thenReturn(Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<IData>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super List<IData>> subscriber) 
                List<IData> data = new ArrayList<IData>() {{
                    add(new Data());
                }};
                subscriber.onNext(data);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }));

        this.interactor.buildUseCaseObservable()

        verify(this.mockedData, times(0)).getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am blind, but which part of your tests will actually trigger a call to *buildUseCaseObservable()*?

Comment: @GhostCat my fault :( sorry, ,I added part, just while creating this post I was playing with code and evidently remove call.

Comment: I am not too much into Mokito; but to me, this code looks ok. Probably you should consider changing the tags ... to JUnit, and maybe add Mokito - to attract some of the more expert users.

Comment: @GhostCat I found solution, if you are interested you can check, in general problem was multithreading and you can't test Rx stuff in that way (in a way how I want to do that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Fortunately I found solution and right way of testing Rx stuff.
I found a [nice article](https://labs.ribot.co.uk/unit-testing-rxjava-6e9540d4a329#.5di8g42wa) with very [helpful class](https://gist.github.com/ivacf/874dcb476bfc97f4d555) called RxAssertions with a small modification of class my tests start passing.

```
public class DataInteractorTest {

    private DataInteractor interactor;

    @Mock private RestService mockedRest;
    @Mock private DataService mockedData;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.interactor = new DataInteractor(mockedRest, mockedData);
    }


    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void downloadDataFromNetwork_ignoreDataFromDatabase() {
        when(mockedRest.getData()).thenReturn(this.getMockedData(4));
        when(mockedData.getData()).thenReturn(this.getMockedData(8));

        RxAssertions.subscribeAssertingThat(this.interactor.buildUseCaseObservable())
            .completesSuccessfully()
            .hasSize(4);
    }

    /**
     * Helper function which return mocked data
     */
    private Observable getMockedData(final int size) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<IData>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<IData>> subscriber) {
            List<IData> data = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                data.add(new Data());
            }
            subscriber.onNext(data);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}
}
```

#### RxAsserations

```
public class RxAssertions {

    public static <T> ObservableAssertions<T> subscribeAssertingThat(Observable<List<T>> observable) {
        return new ObservableAssertions<>(observable);
    }

    public static class ObservableAssertions<T> {

        private List<T> mResult;
        private Throwable mError;
        private boolean mCompleted;

        public ObservableAssertions(Observable<List<T>> observable) {
            mCompleted = false;
            mResult = new ArrayList<>();
            observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<List<T>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            mCompleted = true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable error) {
                            mError = error;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<T> list) {
                            mResult.addAll(list);
                        }
                    });
        }

        public ObservableAssertions<T> completesSuccessfully() {
            if (!mCompleted || mError != null) {
                if (mError != null) mError.printStackTrace();
                throw new AssertionFailedError("Observable has not completed successfully - cause: "
                        + (mError != null ? mError : "onComplete not called"));
            }
            return this;
        }

        public ObservableAssertions<T> fails() {
            if (mError == null) {
                throw new AssertionFailedError("Observable has not failed");
            }
            return this;
        }

        public ObservableAssertions<T> failsWithError(Throwable throwable) {
            fails();
            if (!throwable.equals(mError)) {
                throw new AssertionFailedError("Observable has failed with a different error," +
                        " expected is " + throwable + " but thrown was " + mError);
            }
            return this;
        }

        public ObservableAssertions<T> hasSize(int numItemsExpected) {
            if (numItemsExpected != mResult.size()) {
                throw new AssertionFailedError("Observable has emitted " + mResult.size()
                        + " items but expected was " + numItemsExpected);
            }
            return this;
        }

        @SafeVarargs
        public final ObservableAssertions<T> emits(T... itemsExpected) {
            completesSuccessfully();
            assertEmittedEquals(itemsExpected);
            return this;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public ObservableAssertions<T> emits(Collection<T> itemsExpected) {
            completesSuccessfully();
            assertEmittedEquals((T[]) itemsExpected.toArray());
            return this;
        }

        public ObservableAssertions<T> emitsNothing() {
            completesSuccessfully();
            if (mResult.size() > 0) {
                throw new AssertionFailedError("Observable has emitted " + mResult.size() + " items");
            }
            return this;
        }

        private void assertEmittedEquals(T[] itemsExpected) {
            hasSize(itemsExpected.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsExpected.length; i++) {
                T expected = itemsExpected[i];
                T actual = mResult.get(i);
                if (!expected.equals(actual)) {
                    throw new AssertionFailedError("Emitted item in position " + i + " does not match," +
                            "  expected " + expected + " actual " + actual);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```